# Mockito - deep stubbing

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am using Mockito to test my classes. I am trying to use Deep stubbing as I didn't a way on injecting a Mock inside another mock object in Mockito.

```
class MyService{

    @Resource
    SomeHelper somehelper;

    public void create()
    {
        //....
        somehelper.invokeMeth(t);
    }
}

class SomeHelper{
    @Resource
    private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

    public void invokeMeth(T t)
    {
        try{
            //...
            webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(t);
        }catch (final WebServiceIOException e) {
            throw new MyAppException("Service not running");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to Unit test the MyService class's create() method.
I have injected a mock for SomeHelper as follows

```
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
SomeHelper somehelper;
```

What I want now is when  the invokeMeth() method gets called on the mocked somehelper object it calls the real method in this case.

```
when(somehelper.invokeMeth(isA(RequestObject.class)))
    .thenCallRealMethod();
```

I was expecting the webServiceTemplate not be null in this case.

However I get a Nullpointer exception when the code tries to execute the line

```
webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(t);
```

Any clue how I can get access to a deep mock object (i.e. mock within a mock - in this case webserviceTemplete mock inside somehelper mock) and then apply a when condition to throw a  WebserviceIOException ?
I want this so that I can test the MyService.create() to check it behaves properly when a WebServiceIOException is thrown down the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes of course, you are mixing *real objects* and mocks. Plus using the `thenCallRealMethod` lloks like a partial mock, it feels wrong here, it's no wonder the [javadoc of this method](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenCallRealMethod%28%29) talks about that as well.

I definatelty should stress you than, design wise, having a mock that returns a mock is often a smell. More precisely you are breaking the **Demeter Law**, or not following the **Tell, Don't Ask** principle.

Any looking at your code I don't why the code would need to mock `WebServiceTemplate`. You want to unit test `MyService`, and I don't see a relationship to `WebServiceTemplate`. Instead you should focus on the interactions with you helper only. And unit test `SomeHelper` **separately** where you'll be able to check the interactions between `SomeHelper` and `WebServiceTemplate`.

Here's a little example of how I see the thing:

```
public void ensure_helper_is_used_to_invoke_a_RequestObject() {
  // given a service that has an helper collaborator
  ... other fixture if necessary

  // when
  myService.behaviorToTest();

  // then
  verify(someHelperMock).invokeMeth(isA(RequestObject.class));
}
```

How those that look for your real use case ?

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks brice. Yes I agree with you completely. Thing is if say the service isn't available which is a layer down in the code hierarchy, the MyService create() handles it in a specific way. I agree I can mock out the Error Response and test the same. And that's the right Unit Test. Was actually exploring if need be can we inject a mock in another mock and then apply a when-then-return rule on the injected mock.

Comment: @Soumya _'Was actually exploring if need be can we inject a mock in another mock and then apply a when-then-return rule on the injected mock.'_ No you cannot do that, technically it would be possible but it will breaks the mock semantic, instead you can use a **spy**, however note that in your case it might lead to partial mocking again. The most important thing is to make the test easily maintainable and very readable (expressive but not verbose) ; goals that can be compromised if playing too much with mocks ; I've done that once and it was a mess.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brice. Agree with you.